# Сдвигается блок после обновления другого блока аяксом

Tags: html, css, ajax

В чем может быть проблема, если сдвигается блок при обновлении другого блока аяксом?
Схема блоков такая:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

изначально верхние части `div2` и `iframe` выровнены по верхнему краю.
причем у обоих нет свойств `float`.

`iframe` в коде идет прямо следом за `div2` и становится как показано.

но после нажатия на ссылку в `div1`, обновляется аяксом все, что показано красным и `ifram`e уезжает вверх, как будто у него слетело свойство `margin-top`

из-за чего это происходит?

Comment: исходники в данном вопросе обязательны

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте фиксированную ширину или заверните все в отдельный див с фиксированной шириной.

Arcadiy, отдельный див с фиксированной шириной не подойдет т.к. тогда не получится обновлять только красное